# I have a B1/B2 visa that was applied for a conference in US, but I missed the conference. Can I use my visa for an academic visit?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I am a Chinese national that studied at a US university before and am currently working in India as a postdoctoral researcher. Last year I applied for a B1/B2 visa to attend a conference in the US. I got the visa eventually, but only after the conference.

My question is: can I use the visa (which is multi-entry and has no annotation) for an academic visit? Specifically, I plan to visit my former Ph.D. advisor at a US university for one week but wonder if my visa can be used for this purpose and if there are any restrictions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With no annotation, you can use the B1/B2 visa to enter the US for any [purpose allowed to tourists and business visitors](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) any time during its validity period. It [does not have to be for the original purpose of travel](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-gen-faq.asp#qlistb1b2_5) on your visa application.

Comment: You are usually much more diligent in sourcing your claims. I am under the impression you are correct here but it needs a source.

Comment: @chx There are quite a few. The first example I found is given here. That the US visa is valid in this circumstance is not seriously questioned by anyone. Remember that the visa only allows the holder to travel to a port of entry and request admission. They still have to demonstrate at the border that their purpose of travel qualifies.